# How to create a seamless blender day to night transition using hdr

Tags: video

I making a short animation clip for my website, the video depicts a scene of a mountain across two days an nights.Using a transition between 4 HDR the problem is the transition isn't seamless and highly noticeable I've searched the web but haven't found much more than demonstrations of the transition. Is there a way to seamlessly transition between dawn, morning, noon. evening, night, twilight and dawn again

Comment: Please add images of what your current result is and images/explanation of the setup that isn't working.